# ¿Programa en C++ o Java que funcione como interprete de comandos de Unix?

Tags: java, c++, unix

Quería saber cómo hacer mediante clases de objetos un programa en C++ o en java que sea capaz de implementar las siguientes funciones:

- `string pwd()`: devuelve la ruta completa desde la raíz en el mismo formato que Unix.
- `void ls()`: muestra por pantalla cada archivo, directorio o enlace del directorio actual, uno en cada línea.
- `void cd(string path)`: cambia la ruta a otro directorio, puede ser al directorio padre (`path=".."`), al directorio actual (`path="."`), a un directorio desde la raíz (`path="/...."`) o a un subdirectorio del directorio actual.
- `void stat(string elemento)`: muestra por pantalla el tamaño del archivo, directorio o enlace que se le pasa como parámetro, también se puede pasar una ruta a otro elemento de otro directorio.
- `void vim(string file, int tamanyo)`: cambia el tamaña de un archivo dentro de la ruta actual únicamente, si no existe lo crea nuevo.
- `void mkdir(string directorio)`: crea un directorio dentro de la ruta actual únicamente.
- `void ln(string origen, string destino)`: crea un enlace de nombre "destino" que enlaza al elemento origen, "destino" no puede ser una ruta completa pero "origen" sí, es decir el elemento "origen" puede estar en otro directorio.
- `void rm(string elemento)`: elimina un elemento dentro de la ruta actual o se le puede pasar una ruta completa, si es un archivo lo elimina directamente, si es un enlace, elimina el enlace pero no lo enlazado, y si es un directorio elimina el directorio con todo su contenido.

Debe haber 4 clases distintas: `Directorio`, `Archivo`, `Enlace` y `Ruta` (el constructor será un directorio que actuará de raíz).

Todas las operaciones anteriores se usan sobre la clase `Ruta`.

El archivo principal ya lo tengo hecho tanto en c++ como en java, sólo faltaría la implementación de las clases, aquí adjunto ambos.

C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include "ruta.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Directorio raiz("");
    Ruta ruta(raiz);

    for (bool done=false; !done; )
    {
        string         line,arg;
        vector<string> cmd;

        cout << "~> " << flush;

        getline(cin,line);
        istringstream iss(line);
        while(getline(iss,arg,' ')) cmd.push_back(arg);

        if (cin.eof())
        {
            done = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (cmd.size()<1)
            continue;

        try
        {
            if (cmd[0]=="pwd")
            {
                cout << ruta.pwd() << endl;
            }
            if (cmd[0]=="ls")
            {
                ruta.ls();
            }
            if (cmd[0]=="cd")
            {
                 ruta.cd(cmd.at(1));
            }
            if (cmd[0]=="stat")
            {
                if (cmd.size()>1)
                    ruta.stat(cmd.at(1));
                else
                    ruta.stat(".");
            }
            if (cmd[0]=="vim")
            {
                 ruta.vim(cmd.at(1),atoi(cmd.at(2).c_str()));
            }
            if (cmd[0]=="mkdir")
            {
                 ruta.mkdir(cmd.at(1));
            }
            if (cmd[0]=="ln")
            {
                 ruta.ln(cmd.at(1),cmd.at(2));
            }
            if (cmd[0]=="rm")
            {
                 ruta.rm(cmd.at(1));
            }
            if (cmd[0]=="exit")
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }
        catch (arbol_ficheros_error& e)
        {
             cerr << e.what() << endl;
        }
        catch (out_of_range& e)
        {
             cerr << e.what() << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Directorio raiz;
    Ruta ruta;
    try {
        raiz = new Directorio("");
        ruta = new Ruta(raiz);
    } catch (ExcepcionArbolFicheros e) { return; }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    boolean end = false;

    while (!end)
    { 
         System.out.print(ruta.pwd()+"> ");
         try {
             String[] argv = br.readLine().split(" ");
             if (argv[0].equals("pwd")) {
                 System.out.println(ruta.pwd());
             } else if (argv[0].equals("ls")) {
                 ruta.ls();
             } else if (argv[0].equals("cd")) {
                 ruta.cd(argv[1]);
             } else if (argv[0].equals("stat")) {
                 if (argv.length > 1) ruta.stat(argv[1]);
                 else ruta.stat(".");
             } else if (argv[0].equals("vim")) {
                 ruta.vim(argv[1], Integer.parseInt(argv[2]));
             } else if (argv[0].equals("mkdir")) {
                 ruta.mkdir(argv[1]);
             } else if (argv[0].equals("ln")) {
                 ruta.ln(argv[1],argv[2]);
             } else if (argv[0].equals("rm")) {
                 ruta.rm(argv[1]);
             } else if (argv[0].equals("exit")) {
                 end = true;
             } else {
                 System.out.println("Comando desconocido");
             }
        } catch(ExcepcionArbolFicheros e) {
             System.out.println(e);
        } catch(IOException e) {
             System.out.println("Error de entrada-salida");
        } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
             System.out.println("Error sintactico: parametros insuficientes");
        }
     }
   }
};
```

Comment: Hola Elena, bienvenida a SOes, pregunta, ¿has intentado algo por tu cuenta?

Comment: @Elena adjunta tu código y reporta los problemas que te impiden terminar tu ejercicio o las cuestiones que necesites aclarar, una cosa es pedir ayuda y otra que te hagamos tu trabajo

Comment: Solo me hacía falta ayuda para especificar un poco las clases y como organizarlas, no la implementación en sí.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, *yo no creo que la resolución del problema se deba realizar mediante llamadas al sistema operativo invocando al comando pertinente*(lo mismo estoy equivocado), entre otras cosas porque si Java es portable, los comandos entre sistemas operativos no lo son, y por lo tanto se debería tratar de realizar la funcionalidad mediante el uso de Java.

Independiente de esto te propongo las siguientes clases según te exigen, incluso una más.

La clase **Ruta**, representa un path a un directorio, archivo o enlace y es *inmutable*, es decir, una vez creada no se puede modificar, se crea a partir de un objeto String. Se podría añadir alguna validación.

```
public class Ruta {
  private final String path;

  public Ruta(String path) {
    this.path=path;
  }

  public String getPath() {
    return path;
  }
}
```

Todas las demás clases extienden de la clase **AbstractFileBase**, menos la ya comentada clase **Ruta**. Todas tienen un constructor común, un método *rm()* que funciona igual para todas, puesto que un **Directorio**, un **Archivo** o un **Enlace** se eliminan de la misma forma y un método abstracto *stat()* que tiene una implementación diferente en cada caso, seria algo asi:

```
public abstract class AbstractFileBase {
  protected File file;

  public AbstractFileBase(Ruta ruta) {
    file=new File(ruta.getPath());
  }

  public void rm(Ruta ruta) {
    file=new File(ruta.getPath());
    if(file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
  }

  public abstract String stat() throws IOException;

}
```

La clase **Directorio** implementa los métodos propios:

```
public class Directorio extends AbstractFileBase {
  public Directorio(Ruta ruta) {
    super(ruta);
  }

  public String pwd() throws IOException {
    return file.getCanonicalPath();
  }

  public void mkdir(String path) {
    // :TODO
  }

  public List<String> ls() {
    List<String> files=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(File file:file.listFiles()) {
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            files.add("d - "+file.getName());
        }
        else {
            files.add("f - "+file.getName());
        }
    }
    return files;
  }

  public String cd(Ruta ruta) throws IOException {
    file=new File(ruta.getPath());
    return pwd();
  }

  @Override
  public String stat() throws IOException {
    // :TODO aqui crear la informacion estadistica que se desee
    return "Soy un directorio";
  }

}
```

La clase **Archivo** implementa los métodos propios:

```
public class Archivo extends AbstractFileBase {
  public Archivo(Ruta ruta) {
    super(ruta);
  }

  @Override
  public String stat() throws IOException {
    // :TODO aqui crear la informacion estadistica que se desee
    return "Soy un directorio";
  }

  public void vim(String path,int size) throws IOException {
    // :TODO creo que con la versión Java 7 de File es fácil de implementar
  }

}
```

La clase **Enlace** implementa los métodos propios:

```
public class Enlace extends AbstractFileBase {
  public Enlace(Ruta ruta) {
    super(ruta);
  }

  public void ln(String newDirectory) {
    // :TODO
  }

  @Override
  public String stat() throws IOException {
    // :TODO aqui crear la informacion estadistica que se desee
    return "Soy un directorio";
  }

}
```

- Por ultimo comentarte que si con la clase **File** del JDK no puedes implementar todos los métodos solicitados, puedes intentarlo con [FileUtils de Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)
- Para tu clase **Main** puedes crear la aplicación al estilo CLI(Command Line Interface) de forma muy sencilla utilizando la librería [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/index.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias está muy bien! Lo único que no hay que hacerlo realmente trabajando con el sistema operativo, sino utilizando un entorno virtual, es decir, no existen realmente los directorios, solamente en el programa. Y sí que está permitido añadir clases para ayudar, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Te agradezco mucho el comentario, si no es mucho pedir  te rogaría que dieras por bueno o votaras la respuesta como correcta, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la siguiente clase

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellComand {


public String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}

}
```

y para usar esas funciones seria algo así:

```
ExecuteShellCommand executor = new ExecuteShellCommand();
// para pwd
executor.executeCommand("pwd");
//para ls
executor.executeCommand("ls");
// etc etc...
```

Ahora solo debes crear las clases que mencionas y ejecutar los comandos como mostré arriba

Fuente: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Answer (score 0):

Que te aconsejo tener un txt y en cada linea de este tener un comando de shell, al momento de ingresar la entrada comparas con cada linea del txt con este ejemplo http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/ y para ejecutar el comando  en java

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar map.jar time.rel test.txt debug");
```